# I am unable to write data in Excel Sheet using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

`enter code here`     I am unable to write the data in excel sheet.Initially i am having the data in a list 'ListTickets' and then assigning the value to every cell from the list.But its not working i am getting a blank sheet with no data.

```
 public static void UpdateIncidentExcel(string Incident_Path,List<excelObj> ListTickets)
      {
        //  lastRow = 0;
          MyApp = new Excel.Application();
          //  MyApp.Visible = false;
          MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(Incident_Path);
          MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets["BOXI_summary"]; // Explict cast is not required here
          //lastRow = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;
          int j=(ListTickets.Count() == 1) ? 3 : (ListTickets.Count() == 2) ? 4 : ListTickets.Count();
          for (int i = 2; i < j; i++)
          {
              int k = i - 2;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 1] = ListTickets[k].Bundle_Name;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 2] = ListTickets[k].Incident_Number;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 3] = ListTickets[k].Status_Symbol;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 4] = ListTickets[k].Aging;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 5] = ListTickets[k].Incident_Area;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 6] = ListTickets[k].Service_Call_Type;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 7] = ListTickets[k].Assigned_To_Workgroup;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 8] = ListTickets[k].Assigned_To_Name;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 9] = ListTickets[k].Assignee_LAN_ID;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 10] = ListTickets[k].Open_Date;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 11] = ListTickets[k].Close_Date;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 12] = ListTickets[k].Resolve_Date;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 13] = ListTickets[k].Last_Modified_Date;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 14] = ListTickets[k].Application_ID;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 15] = ListTickets[k].AMS_Application_Name;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 16] = ListTickets[k].Tier;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 17] = ListTickets[k].Priority_Symbol;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 18] = ListTickets[k].Application_Class;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 19] = ListTickets[k].Contains_PHI_SPI;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 20] = ListTickets[k].Reach_Back_Required;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 21] = ListTickets[k].Parent_Number;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 22] = ListTickets[k].Vendor_Engagement_Date;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 23] = ListTickets[k].Vendor_Response_Date;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 24] = ListTickets[k].Problem_Number;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 25] = ListTickets[k].Caused_By_Change_Order_Number;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 26] = ListTickets[k].Change_Number;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 27] = ListTickets[k].Hold_Date;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 28] = ListTickets[k].Reason_Dependency;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 29] = ListTickets[k].Resolution_Next_Update_Date;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 30] = ListTickets[k].Resolution_Method_Description;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 31] = ListTickets[k].Resolution_Code_Description;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 32] = ListTickets[k].Hours_of_Availability;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 33] = ListTickets[k].Core_Hours_Mon_Fri;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 34] = ListTickets[k].Core_Hours_Saturday;
              MySheet.Cells[i, 35] = ListTickets[k].Core_Hours_Sunday;
          }
          MyBook.Save();
          MyBook.Close(0);
          MyApp.Quit();
          // Call the garbage collector to collect and wait for finalizers to finish.
          GC.Collect();
          GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
          // Release the COM objects that have been instantiated.
          Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(MyBook);
          Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(MySheet);
          Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(MyApp);
      }
    }
```

Comment: This could be because ListTickets' values are "" or because i is equal to j.

Comment: Thank you trinalbadger. It answered my question.Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Just a friendly FYI, the Excel interop object you're using is designed for client/desktop applications only.  Microsoft does not support or recommend using any Office interop (automation) objects on a server.  They are very inefficient, can have security issues and often cause serious memory leaks.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

I've tried a few different strategies for creating Excel files on a server and my favorite is programmatically creating an Excel XML file within the response.  It's fast, lightweight and gives you the ability to do all the formatting you want.  The only downside is the client has to manually save it as a .xlsx to get all of the Excel functionality on their side.